# Getter Property (without property and setter) Access Via ValueStack

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, valuestack

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport
{
     public String getMyValue()
     {
          return "SomeText";
     }
     ...
}
```

I have this `MyAction` class. Now, the question is that when I refer `myValue` in my JSP page using OGNL, will it create the `myValue` property on `ValueStack`, or will it just call the getter method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will call a getter method. The OGNL when evaluating an expression finding a property accessor corresponding to the name of the property. It's doing it using reflection on the method basis via prefixing `"get"`/`"set"` to the name of the property.