# Cannot acces to variable set on Struts jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts

I am having some troubles in my project. Actual state is that I am in charge of fixing bugs after other people made a migration to Struts 2.

Right now, I am having some troubles with some jsp files that generate some reports. They share some elements that are added with the `<%@ include file="file.jsp" %>`like for example *"KeyDate"* *"country"* *"organisation"* and so on. This are parameters to make restrictions when generating the reports. Therefore they are added from other files which include the snippets with the corresponding tags to allow reuse.

This is the former version which was working (snippet of file):

```
<c:set var="keyDateProperty" value="keyDate"></c:set>

<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/include/reports/reportKeyDate.jsp" %>
```

And the reportKeyDate.jsp:

```
            <td><p id="labelKeyDate"><bean:message key="label.keyDate"/>*</p></td>
            <td colspan="2"><p>
                <html:text styleId="fieldKeyDate" style="width: 90%;" 
                    readonly="true" disabled="${readOnly}" property="${keyDateProperty}" 
                    errorStyleClass="inputError" onkeyup="updateCurrentFilterCriteria();" />
                    <html:messages id="error" property="${keyDateProperty}">
                        <p class="error"><c:out value="${error}" /></p>
                    </html:messages>
                <img id="imgKeyKdate" style="cursor: pointer; vertical-align: middle;" 
                    src="img/iconCalendar.gif" 
                    title="<bean:message key="tooltip.chooseDate"/>" alt="">
            </p></td>
```

So far so good. This is how it looks after the migration:

```
<s:set var="keyDateProperty" value="keyDate"></s:set>

<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/include/reports/reportKeyDate.jsp" %>
```

And the reportKeyDate.jsp:

```
            <td><p id="labelKeyDate"><s:text name="label.keyDate"/>*</p></td>
            <td colspan="2"><p>
                <s:textfield id="fieldKeyDate" style="width: 90%;" 
                    readonly="true" disabled="%{#attr.readOnly}" name="%{keyDateProperty}" 
                    cssErrorclass="inputError" onkeyup="updateCurrentFilterCriteria();" />
                    <s:fielderror fieldName="%{keyDateProperty}" />
                <img id="imgKeyKdate" style="cursor: pointer; vertical-align: middle;" 
                    src="img/iconCalendar.gif" 
                    title="<s:text name='tooltip.chooseDate'/>" alt="">
            </p></td>
```

So basically `html:` tags have been migrated to `s:`.

As you guys can see the name of the variable to point to the struts form element is set on the top with `s:set` and then accessed on the included snippet. This is apparently which is not working. I have tried to debug the method `setKeyDate()` and it is not being called. I have tried to add the snippet directly to the file and defining the `name` attribute directly to `keyDate` and it works when I debugged it.

Any suggestion or ideas are welcome!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Roman C , you spot on. Thanks man

Comment: @atiqkhaled you are awesome :) read http://stackoverflow.com/a/26753584/573032

Comment: Oh thanks for sharing. :)

Comment: thanks @RomanC, that helped me to find the issue.